# Failed to get type of condition exception when applying personalization rule, based on QueryString

Tags: personalization, rules-engine

We are trying to personalize a component based on a Device Detection rule `where the query string matches value`. 
This is not working properly and below error is getting logged in Sitecore logs.

**Any one faced this issue earlier?**

```
ERROR Failed to get type of condition
Exception: System.ArgumentException
Message: GenericArguments[0], 'Sitecore.Rules.ConditionalRenderings.ConditionalRenderingsRuleContext', on 'Sitecore.Rules.Devices.QueryStringCondition`1[T]' violates the constraint of type 'T'.
Source: mscorlib
  at System.RuntimeType.ValidateGenericArguments(MemberInfo definition, RuntimeType[] genericArguments, Exception e)
  at System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)
  at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.GetGenericType(String typeName, Type genericArgumentType)
  at Sitecore.Rules.DefaultRuleFactory.GetRuleCondition[T](Database database, XElement element)
Nested Exception:
Exception: System.TypeLoadException
Message: GenericArguments[0], 'Sitecore.Rules.ConditionalRenderings.ConditionalRenderingsRuleContext', on 'Sitecore.Rules.Devices.QueryStringCondition`1[T]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.
Source: mscorlib
  at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(RuntimeTypeHandle handle, IntPtr* pInst, Int32 numGenericArgs, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
  at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(Type[] inst)
  at System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)
```

Comment: Can you add code that is causing the error?

Comment: Sorry, we are using out of the box rule. There is no custom code.

Comment: Can you open /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Device Detection/Query String item in master database and check that field Type has "Sitecore.Rules.Devices.QueryStringCondition,Sitecore.Kernel" value?

Comment: @Anton, yes we have the same value there. "Sitecore.Rules.Devices.QueryStringCondition,Sitecore.Kernel"

Comment: did you do a Sitecore upgrade before it appeared? maybe the one of Sitecore dll-s not correct.

Comment: Not sure, we have Sitecore 8.2 with Update 3. All other rules are working fine. Have checked the Sitecore Kernel DLL and all the code looks OK.

Comment: @ManoharaPrasad - Did you find the solution for same?